# Current location outside of UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, core-location, cllocationmanager

Is there way I can get current location without using UIViewController?

I'm making a SDK and I don't want to make UIViewController in it. I want to make only modal classes. I'm looking a way to avoid UIViewControllers completely for this SDK.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Yes, just use an instance of `CLLocationManager`

Comment: Is there any dependency between `CoreLocation` and `UIViewController/UIKit`?

Comment: @Kamran: No. There's not

Comment: @Paulw11 Can you please send a code snipped for use of `CLLocationManager`?